# How to I make a shared Linux folder a mapped network drive?

Tags: linux, network-shares

I have a Raspberry Pi running Debian. I would like to make a directory a mapped network drive accessible by other PCs connected to my home network. The directory is: /home/user/Public

The Public folder has view and access content available to anyone. However, when I try to map the folder on Windows \computer-ip\user\Public or Chromebook //computer-ip/user/Public it says it can't be accessed.

I know I'm missing something here. How can I get other computers to access the Raspberry Pi on the same local network?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because a user is allowed to access a drive doesn't mean they are authorized to use the content in any way. Make sure that file ownership and permissions match what user you intend to share this out to. In more complex system with multiple users, you may have to use ACLs or groups to accomplish this goal. This is probably the most troublesome component of network filesystems using any fairly advanced protocol. The best way to get around permissions and ownership issues is to integrate your systems into a directory platform such as AD or FreeIPA.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install and configure Samba, which implements the SMB protocol used by Windows.

One note: unless you have some really old Windows machines--before Windows Vista--I would disable SMBv1 on Samba for better performance and security.